# '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, immutability, nsmutabledictionary

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)updateTemplates:(NSMutableDictionary *)oldTemplates
                             forSpecType:(NSString *)specType {
    // oldTemplates is an NSMutableDictionary pulled from a plist
    // specType is used for flexible paths, to eliminate duplicate code

    // Make a dict of the parameters object (about to be overwritten)
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [oldTemplates valueForKeyPath:
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"root.%@.parameters", specType]];

    // Dump the new data into the matching object
    [oldTemplates setValue:[updateTemplates valueForKeyPath:
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data.%@", specType]]
                forKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"root.%@", specType]];

    // Put the parameters back, since they don't exist anymore
    /* Instant crash, with the debugger claiming something is immutable
     * But I just used the exact same method on the line above
     * updateTemplates isn't immutable either; it's only when I try to mutate
       oldTemplates after putting in updateTemplates -- and only the update
       seems to be breaking things -- that I get the exception and crash
    */
    [oldTemplates setValue:parameters forKeyPath:
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"root.%@.parameters", specType]];

    return oldTemplates;
}
```

I could set up a loop to write one object of `updateTemplates.specType` at a time so only those parts get replaced and then I don't have to do anything with the parameters, but if it's immutable now, it will be when I try to write to it again. That won't do me any good.

Comment: It might be good to log both `oldTemplates` and `parameters` just to see what types the runtime thinks they are.  (Does the error give an object address?  If so, does it match one of the dictionaries you're using in this code?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mutableCopy` makes a shallow mutable copy, not a deep mutable copy.   If you have an `NSDictionary` containing key/value pairs where the values are `NSDictionary` instances, `mutableCopy` will return a mutable dictionary containing those `NSDictionary` immutable instances as values.

You either need to do a deep copy or use the plist serialization functionality to decode the plist with the mutable collections option enabled.    Or you could compose a new collection derived from the old.

Comment: I did have NSJSONSerialization running with kNilOptions. Oops.

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, dictionaries created from plists or NSUserDefaults are immutable by default. You'll have to create a mutable copy manually:

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[oldTemplates valueForKeyPath:
           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"root.%@.parameters", specType]] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Doesn't matter. Everywhere else I get an NSMutableDictionary from a plist, I can mutate it normally. -- Xcode just froze up again. -- If  I try calling `setObject:forKey:` on `updateTemplates`, it keeps running and I can log the object. So the update isn't immutable. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
NSMutableDictionary* oldTemplates = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[oldTemplates valueForKeyPath:
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"root.%@.parameters", specType]]];
```

This will create a mutable copy from an existing NSDictionary